# Geometric constructions with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to do basic geometric using tikz like angle bisectors, bisection of line segments, inscribed circles, circumscribed circles etc.? More in detail I want a command which takes three points (not on one line) as argument and gives me the (inscribed) circumscribed circle of the triangle defined by this points. Analogously I want a command which takes two points and gives me the bisection of the line segment defined by those points, similar in the case of angle bisection.

Comment: @user4011: I removed the {geometry} tag because it deals with the package of the same name which can be used to change text block margins (and has nothing to do with TikZ).

Comment: @lockstep: Ok, thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: Have a look at the `calc` library of TikZ, but also the `intersections` and `fit` libraries should be relevant. They are described in the `pgfmanual`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`tkz-euclide` provides commands for many geometric constructions. It is available on [Altermundus' site](http://www.altermundus.fr/pages/euclide.html) and [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide). The manual is quite good (except that the command `tkzDrawPolygon` used in many examples doesn't exist), but only available in French (though even if you don't speak French, you should be able to figure everything out from the examples). I have never used it before, but was able to draw the following in a few minutes:

[image: triangle with in- and circumcircle]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % The triangle
    \tkzDefPoint(2,2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(5,-2){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,-2){C}
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)

    % circumcircle
    \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{G}
    \tkzDrawPoint(G)
    \tkzDrawCircle(G,A)

    % incircle
    \tkzDefCircle[in](A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{I}\tkzGetLength{rIN}
    \tkzDrawPoint(I)
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](I,\rIN pt)

    \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below left](C)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above left](A,I,G)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes you need to add `\usetkzobj{all}`, some objects are not necessary and it's possible to avoid some of them but you need to read the doc to know what you want and what you need. I put this week the source of all my docs on ctan.

Comment: Just looked around, the documentation is now in English (very readable, even though the author warns he isn't a native speaker).